# Area chart from irregular / duplicate dates

Tags: d3.js

I have a JSON dataset like this:

```
"document": [
                {
                    "id": "123",
                    "date": "01/01/2001"
                },
                {
                    "id": "124",
                    "date": "01/01/2001"
                },
                {
                    "id": "125",
                    "date": "02/01/2001"
                },
                {
                    "id": "126",
                    "date": "31/01/2001"
                },
                {
                    "id": "127",
                    "date": "31/01/2001"
                }
]
```

I need to create an area chart that shows document count / time.

[image: Simple Chart]

So, do I need to preprocess the data into something like this:

```
"document": [
                {
                    "date": "01/01/2001",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "date": "02/01/2001",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "date": "31/01/2001",
                    "count": 2
                }
]
```

Or, will D3 automagically do this for me somehow? Seems like the type of thing it can do?

Many Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest):

```
> d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){ return d.date; })
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
    .entries(data)

[{"key":"01/01/2001","values":2},
 {"key":"02/01/2001","values":1},
 {"key":"31/01/2001","values":2}]
```

(data should be set equal to the array you posted)

Some [examples and explanations](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) to complement the office docs.